# database results getting repeated

Tags: magento-1.8, php, database

I am trying to get results from database . For now i tried to take out title from a custom table i made . All is working well except that there are only two rows with one title in each in that table but when the result outputs through echo each of them are repeated four times . My code is

```
<div class="block-content-col">
<ul>
<?php
$collection = Mage::getModel('example/example')->getCollection();
$keys = array_keys($collection->getFirstItem()->getData());
foreach ($keys as $key){ // loop through all the keys (fname, lname, email... 
    foreach ($collection as $obj){//loop throught each object 


?>

<li class="col-item">
<div>
<span>  <?php  echo $obj->getData("title");//get the value for a speficic key. ?></span>
</div>
</li>


<?php
    } 
}
?>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looping through the keys has no real use here as far as I can see.

```
<div class="block-content-col">
<ul>
<?php
$collection = Mage::getModel('example/example')->getCollection();
foreach ($collection as $obj){//loop throught each object 
?>
   <li class="col-item">
   <div><span><?php  echo $obj->getData("title");//get the value for a speficic key. ?></span></div>
   </li>
<?php
}
?>
</ul>
</div>
```

Would still output a list with the `title` of each item in the database as, I think, you intended.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should reverce your foreach loops

```
foreach ($collection as $obj){//loop throught each object 
    foreach ($keys as $key){ // loop through all the keys (fname, lname, email...
```